# Hardware Compatibility

Tags: 12.04, hardware, raid

I am looking into buying a LENOVO RD330 SERVER with a ThinkServer RAID 500 Adapter II RAID controller. I am having problems finding out if all of the hardware that I am wanting will be compatible with Ubuntu. I have check the "Certified Hardware" list but the list is very limited. Both the computer and the RAID controller say they support RedHat and Suse but obviously Ubuntu isn't mentioned. I have talked with my vendor and they also not certain if this hardware will work. I have also Google around and the RAID controller appears to be an LSI chipset. But again I haven't been able to find any definitive information saying that this will work.

Any suggestions on how I can find out if the hardware will work?

Answer (score 0):

Yep, not yet certified as per servers list at http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/make/Lenovo/?csrfmiddlewaretoken=APa9wbjmccASFbaEY2WU8MyI96uWT72k&query=&category=Server&release=&level=Any  so I would instead suggest a visit to http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Linux-Discussion/bd-p/Special_Interest_Linux where you can perhaps get an answer direct from Lenovo or http://shop.lenovo.com/us/en/landing_pages/contact/ lists a number to call.